# What exactly does 阅兵 mean/translate as?

Tags: translation, meaning

The word 阅兵 has been used a lot the last couple of days, for obvious reasons, mostly for one specific *activity*. Dictionaries define as follows:

[CC-CEDICT](http://www.mdbg.net/chindict/chindict.php?page=worddict&wdrst=0&wdqb=%E9%98%85%E5%85%B5)

> to review troops

[KEY](http://www.cjkware.com/search?id=%22%E9%96%B2%E5%85%B5%2F%E9%98%85%E5%85%B5%2Fyu%C3%A8b%C4%ABng%22&query=%E9%98%85%E5%85%B5)

> ◊ review troops

[zdic](http://www.zdic.net/c/5/160/359767.htm)

> [military review;review troops] 即检阅车马兵员装备等

but these don't *really* fit...

[BBC Asia](http://www.bbc.com/news/world/asia)

> [image: bbc]

calls it a

> parade

and a

> war show

- What exactly does 阅兵 mean/translate as?

[we're talking about the "parade"/"show" here]

Comment: Why would it not translate as 'military parade'? Or literally 'watching/inspecting the troops'.

Comment: @DrunkenMaster military parade is pretty good, I just wasn't sure if there was a more appropriate term.

Comment: A military parade is, in its standard English meaning, a drill when it is done for practice, or a review of the troops when it is done to be seen-- either by officers or the public.  Of course a circus parade or a parade of stars or what have you is quite a different thing.  But a public military parade is a troop review, or in other words the public is watching/inspecting the troops..  See the helpful discussion at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Military_parade

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Generally I think BBC is a good place to learn English. As "阅兵" is a pretty big event recently, you can see it on news in most English speaking countries. So, just take a look of a news title from BBC: [China military parade commemorates WW2 victory over Japan](http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/world-asia-china-34125418).

"Military parade" looks good to me. However, if you are one of the officials, then you are in a different position. You would call it "review troops". But for outsiders like us, it's an event, a "military parade".

Answer (score -1):

阅兵 should be always translated into "Military Parade". Period.